# How to update child node data in Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Actually I have a database,in which there are multiple users. Each user has his own data,which also includes an array of objects of type "Task".What I want to do is update a particular task's data .I tried  `ref.child (userId).child ("Tasks").child ("done").setValue (isDone);` ,but a new entry is added in the database.So my question is ,how to update the child node's data when we don't know the UID of that node ? I'm adding the snapshot of my database,here the users have UID and under that there is TASKS which contains task's data ,so I have to update the particular task's data ,hoe to do that?? Please help.

[image]

I tried Peter's solution, but the data is getting updated as follows:

[image]

But only the "done" should be updated.

Comment: You can not do that without UID

Comment: @Sid who is updating it? Is it the user with that uid or an admin. If its the user u can get it user.getUid()

Comment: @PeterHaddad the user is updating it and i have the user id .I have to get the task id ,which is to be updated.Like the user wants to update task 2,so I want to get the id of task 2 to update it

Comment: yes this is because you are not writing the child("name") and child("priority") when retrieving.`String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();` and this `String priorities=datas.child("priority").getValue().toString();`

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userId).child("Tasks");

 ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(nameofthetask).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
             for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) { 
              String key=datas.getKey();
              String name=datas.child("name").getValue().toString();
              String priorities=datas.child("priority").getValue().toString();
              ref.child(key).child("done").setValue(isdone);
              ref.child(key).child("name").setValue(name);
              ref.child(key).child("priority").setValue(priorities);

                }
             } 
          }
            @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

           }

     });
```

Can do the above, since the user is updating the task, then you can do a query which will be equalto the task that the user is updating. Then you check if it exists in the database under the user's node and you update the child `done`.

Explanation:

First, you reference the dataSnapshot in this case it is Tasks:

```
  DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(userId).child("Tasks");
```

Now we are here:

```
       users
          userId
             Tasks <----- here
```

Second,  by using this `ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(nameofthetask)`. It is like saying where the child `name` is equal to the task called : task 1.

Third, `if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {` checking if all of the above exists in the database.

Fourth, looping inside the direct children of the node `Tasks` thus I will be able to get the key. `String key=datas.getKey();` that should be the key of the `name` written above example:

```
  users
      userId
         Tasks
            123456 <----------- this will be the key retrieved.
               name: task 1
               done: false
               priority: 5
```

After that I also retrieve the `name` and `priority` as it is needed so the node won't be overriden without the `name` and `priority`.

After retrieving the above:

```
    ref.child(key).child("done").setValue(isdone);
    ref.child(key).child("name").setValue(name);
    ref.child(key).child("priority").setValue(priorities);
```

I use the above code to update all 3 attributes under the key node. This should not create another key node as it already exists in the database and there cant be two keys that are the same. So this will happen:

(before `setValue()`)

```
users
  userId
     Tasks
        123456 
           name: task 1
           done: false <------ We need to update done
           priority: 5
```

(after `setValue()`)

```
users
   userId
      Tasks
         123456 
            name: task 1
            done: true <------ updated
            priority: 5
```

Comment: it is adding new node under the task

Comment: yes I did,it added the new node after the last task

Comment: @Sid Peter's snippet show the correct approach: you need to run a query to determine what nodes/keys match your needs. If you're having trouble making Peter's solution work, edit your question to show what you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Chandresh Tarasariya's answer is incomplete. Peter's answer should work but there is also another approach. In order to update a value of a child in a Firebase database, you need to have it's reference. With other other words, you need to have the value of all nodes that are composing the reference. In your case, a new child is added because you are using a wrong reference. As you can see, the child is added in the wrong place because your don't use the `taskId` in your code.

If you are using this line of code:

```
mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("Tasks").child(taskId).child("done").setValue(true);
```

The value of `taskId` is missing. So how can you sove this problem?

By the time you are adding the data to your database and you are using the push() method to generate that random key, store that key in variable like this:

```
String taskKey = mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("Tasks").push().getKey();
```

So having this key, you can now use it in your reference like this:

```
mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("Tasks").child(taskKey).child("done").setValue(true);
```

Comment: this generates a new key

Comment: That's correct. I'm talking about new data that you will add. The flow is this: generate new key -> store it in a variable -> use the variable in your reference. You cannot use in your reference something that you don't have. Does it work?

Comment: As i said, you cannot update a child that you don't know which one is. How can this possible be? It cannot. Imagine, i'm generating 1000 push ids and I want to update one of them? Which one will I update? Can you do this? You cannot, because you don't have any relationship with none of them. Fist I need to create the relationshion, store the id into a variabile and then reffer to that chil based on that id. Did you understand now?

Comment: You cannot get a single child, because you don't know which one to choose. You can choose a child only when you know the id. Or you can loop through the entire node and get all ids. This is possible but not only one. Ok?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the Firebase with the below code also. If you have used HashMap to create the ask data

The fuser.getUid can be mailId - Use to auth the firebase

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tasks").child(fuser.getUid());
                HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                map.put("name", ""+"XXXX");
                map.put("priority", ""+"6");
                reference.updateChildren(map);
```

This can be done for all the other value also.

Answer (score -1):

```
 mFirebaseDatabase.child(userId).child("Tasks").child(taskId).child("done").setValue(true);
```

Comment: how do I get the taskId ?

Comment: do you want to update done status for all tasks of particular user?